# Options for boosting signal over DSL/live match for Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-network

I have DSL and where I live we do not have that choice (I live in a rural area and do not have the option of cable). I have a NETGEAR WN2000RPT wireless extender I use to connect to Xbox Live. The extender tells me if I have restricted internet access though (i.e. red light for restricted NAT or slow internet and green for okay). Currently, I connect to a netgear wireless router and have been for awhile. Until recently, when I changed the router and DSL filter it was restrictive and giving me red lights for the internet connection same as the Xbox 360. Sometimes, the Xbox 360 would be green on the NAT test while the wireless extender was red.
So, my question is what can I buy to get the most out of my DSL connection? In addition,  what are some suggestions of top Satellite providers or alterative forms of internet connection for rural areas around KY and south if it will not.improve my speed much?
Notes about connection:
1. ADSL from what I can gather.
2. ISP AT&T(no choice because ATT owns the road I am on and no other ISP will deal with us).
3. Tried a while back to ask for a phone line replacement for our road because we are 5 minutes from a major highway and AT&T gives us the runaround they will upgrade the line but does nothing. 
4. Connection speed: 1.5 mbps.

Comment: http://www.gamespot.com/forums/xbox-discussion-1000003/how-do-i-make-my-nat-type-open-29334174/

Comment: Sometimes, the wireless extender has been known to fool my Xbox 360 into think. I have tried it once though.

Comment: Have you tried running some basic wireless tests to see if you are getting WiFi interference?

Comment: Yes, it seems before some interference had a play. However, I have ruled it down to mostly my DSL line but ATT keeps giving us the run around arggh! I am at about 1.38 mbps current speed after the new DSL filter mentioned above. Is it possible for fiber or alterative connection my area (central ky)?

Comment: We aren't the people to ask about what Internet is available in your area :p.  Unfortunately you will have to deal with the evil North American ISPs

Comment: :(. Can you suggest alterative forms of internet connections? I thought about broadband over electric lines but sadly our electric company does not offer it yet.

Comment: Like I said, it depends where you are. DSL/Cable are your best bet if fiber isn't available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you have provided, your only recourse is find another provider, or request AT&T service your connection.

The two key issues you're dealing with though are 1) distance from the nearest Telco hub from your house and 2) if you're on copper and within range, find out if it is "conditioned copper" and if not, can they install that for your line.

FWIW, [DSL Reports](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/4676) is an invaluable site for information about DSL and other broadband related concerns. The FAQ page I've linked you to has expected impact on performance by range for DSL... there's lots of good info on the site, links to tools and very well informed people.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for mentioning it. I think I will re-check here soon about BPL (Broadband over power lines) here soon because other towns with enough customers complaining usually end up with the service soon after. A few rural communities in my state have had that happen.